# Lazarus Debugando

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, debug, lazarus

No delphi em modo de debug eu consigo verificar o valor de um campo, por exemplo:

```
if Edit.text = '' then
```

Se passar o mouse por cima do Edit vou consegui visualizar o valor do campo.

Como eu faço isso no Lazarus? Ou se existe outra forma de visualizar os valores dos campos em modo de debug.

Answer (score 0):

No Delphi é isto mesmo, passar o mouse por cima ou pressionar Ctrl+F7.

Assim também como no Delphi, você precisa enviar o campo em questão para a *Watch List*, dessa forma você conseguira acompanhar a evolução dos valores em modo Debug.

Procure algo como "Castalia for Larazus" acredito que ja possua para ele no github.

[Como configurar a Watch List no Lazarus](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/IDE_Window:_Watch_list)

Answer (score 0):

No Lazarus vá em *View->Debug Windows->Local Variables* e *View->Debug Windows->Watches* juntas chegam a ser mais poderosas que a ferramenta do Delphi, mas não são tão simples

Comment: Porque "juntas chegam a ser mais poderosas que a ferramenta do Delphi", uma vez que o Delphi possui as duas?

Comment: Sarcasmo é contra-producente. Se que me corrigir, corrija, simples assim.

Comment: Opa, entendeu errado, foi uma pergunta mesmo amigo. De Lazarus tenho pouca bagagem, a intenção é entender a diferença.